# Git tab not opening and 'commit' not working in RStudio

Tags: git, github, rstudio

I've been trying to commit changes to GitHub repository with RStudio.

I've installed git correctly (Git Bash commits, pushes and pulls fine), I've directed RStudio to the git.exe, I can see vertical "git" button and "git" tab next to Environment and History, everything looks ok.
However, this "git" tab shows the "spinning wheel" when I try to open it, and some unreadable error message ('?'s in rombs) pops up when I press "commit".

What may be wrong?